# Using the Vimeo API & caching responses in modx

Tags: php, modx, vimeo-api

Our site uses the Vimeo PHP library (https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo.php).

Currently I'm calling the library within snippets, e.g.:

```
require_once("____/autoload.php");
$vimeo = new \Vimeo\Vimeo(____AuthKeys, etc.___);
...
$videos = $vimeo->request('/me/albums/____)['body']['data']
...
```

But this means way more calls to the API than necessary ... right?

Vimeo recommends caching the response, but I'm not sure how to do that in modx.

I'm guessing the first 3 lines only need to be run once, then cached ... until we make changes to our Vimeo account (add videos, albums, etc.)

What's the best way to accomplish this?

The only part that changes from snippet to snippet is the `$vimeo->request...` portion ... is there a way to only have that at the start of our snippets?

Comment: You can use getCache https://modx.com/extras/package/getcache

Answer (score 0):

You can use getCache to cache the complete *output* for a longer period of time, but if you want to cache data inside your *snippet*, you can use the modCacheManager for that.

For example, that might look like this:

```
require_once("____/autoload.php");
$vimeo = new \Vimeo\Vimeo(____AuthKeys, etc.___);
...
$cacheManager = $modx->getCacheManager();
$videos = $cacheManager->get('vimeo_videos');
if (empty($videos)) {
    $videos = $vimeo->request('/me/albums/____')['body']['data']
    $cacheManager->set('vimeo_videos', $videos, 3600);
}
// Process $videos further
```

That will cache the data for one hour (note the 3600 in the set call).